# how to do IIS 6 hard reset

Tags: iis, windows-xp

Some background:

I installed [Debug Diagnostic Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en) to find what was causing a webservice to crash. After hooking up on w3wp, IIS started to crash on any request and stop the application pool. The debugger tool just crashed as well, so obvisously id did something wrong. Anyways, I uninstalled the debugger tool, but the problem keeps persisting. I got this error in the event log:

> Application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is
>   being automatically disabled due to a
>   series of failures in the process(es)
>   serving that application pool.

...and if I restart the DefaultAppPool, it just dies on the next request. So I did the following:

- uninstalled IIS using add/remove windows components
- deleted c:\inetpub\ just to be sure.
- reboot
- installed IIS using add/remove windows components

The problem still persists after these steps.

How can get a "Fresh IIS 6 install" without reinstalling the os? I am running XP Pro x64, if that's important.

Comment: You will probably get a much better answer on Serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

See if this Microsoft Support article helps:

[A user receives a "Service Unavailable" error message when the user browses your Web site that is hosted on IIS 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885654)

**EDIT**

See also this article:
[How to remove and reinstall IIS 5.0, 5.1 and 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325889)
and especially the section "Remove IIS 5.1 or IIS 6.0 ".

Comment: Thanks, but I ran into this article first thing and I have not found any issues with registry access. Unfortunately that does not exclude the fact that it might be a cause. Maybe IIS is just to integrated into the os for me to be able to do a "Clean install".

Comment: See my edit. [15chars]